# How to create stacked bar graph using uibezierpath in ios with different colors

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

Please help me to create a stacked bar graph using only one bezier path. I am creating bar by using below code

```
//creating graph path
UIBezierPath *graph = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
[graph setLineWidth:_barWidth - _barWidth*0.1];

//Creating graph layout
self.graphLayout = [CAShapeLayer layer];
self.graphLayout.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
self.graphLayout.strokeColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
self.graphLayout.lineWidth = _barWidth - _barWidth*0.1;;
self.graphLayout.path = [graph CGPath];
_graphLayout.lineCap = @"round";
_graphLayout.lineJoin = @"round";

[self.layer addSublayer:self.graphLayout];


for (DataSource *dataSource in self.graphCoordinateArray)
{
    [graph moveToPoint:CGPointMake((dataSource.postion*_barWidth) + _barWidth/2, STARTING_Y)];
    [graph addLineToPoint: CGPointMake((dataSource.postion*_barWidth) + _barWidth/2, dataSource.y)];
}
```

[image: I need some thing like this]

Comment: Can you be more specific into what you are doing and what you are looking for?

Comment: I have added reference image please check it.

Comment: You cannot have one bezier with multiple colors. One bezier will go with one color.

Comment: This one does it perfectly https://github.com/sbossak/SBStackedBarChart

Comment: Thanks I will check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on  sectors you need, you must create that many **UIBezierPaths** and  **CAShapeLayer**. So since your stacked bar graph needs 3 sectors, you need 3 UIBeziersPaths and CAShapeLayer

Here is what you need to do:

- Draw one sector using one **UIBezierPath** and one **CAShapeLayer**. After drawing each bar store end points in an array which you will
  need to for second UIBeziersPath i.e, for the second sector.
- Draw second sector UIBeziersPath using End point array from first    sector and do the same for the 3rd sector.

Following is the code that you can try:

```
     UIBezierPath *path1 = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
     [[UIColor grayColor] setStroke];

     UIBezierPath *path2 = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
     [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

      UIBezierPath *path3 = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
     [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];     

     //CAShapeLayer for graph allocation
     CAShapeLayer *path1GraphLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
     path1GraphLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height*0.9);
     path1GraphLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
     UIColor *color = [UIColor greenColor];
     path1GraphLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
     path1GraphLayer.lineWidth = 9;

     //CAShapeLayer for graph allocation
     CAShapeLayer *path2GraphLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
     path2GraphLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height*0.9);
     path2GraphLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
     UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
     path2GraphLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
     path2GraphLayer.lineWidth = 9;

     //CAShapeLayer for graph allocation
     CAShapeLayer *path3GraphLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
     path3GraphLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height*0.9);
     path3GraphLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
     UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];
     path3GraphLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
     path3GraphLayer.lineWidth = 9;



    //Data count means the number of stack bars you need
    for(int i=0 ;i<data.count;i++)
    {
    //path1Value, path2Value, path3Value are values of each sector, get these from a data source which you need to create

     float maxTotalValue = path1Value+path2Value+path3Value;
     float path1Percentage = (float)path1Value/ (float)maxTotalValue;
     float path2Percentage = (float)path2Value/ (float)maxTotalValue;
     float path3Percentage = (float)path3Value/ (float)maxTotalValue;

     //_spacing is the space between each bars you want to maintain

     [path1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake((self.frame.size.width*0.1)+_spacing, (self.frame.size.height*0.9))];

     [path1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.1+_spacing,(self.frame.size.height*0.9)-((self.frame.size.height*0.9)*(1 - path1Percentage)))];

     [path2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.1+_spacing,(self.frame.size.height*0.9)-((self.frame.size.height*0.9)*(1 -path1Percentage)))];

     [path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.1+_spacing,(self.frame.size.height*0.9)-((self.frame.size.height*0.9)*(1 -path2StatePercentage - path1StatePercentage )))];

     [path3 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.1+_spacing,(self.frame.size.height*0.9)-((self.frame.size.height*0.9)*(1 -path2StatePercentage - path1StatePercentage )))];

     [path3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.1+_spacing,(self.frame.size.height*0.9)-((self.frame.size.height*0.9)*(1 -path2StatePercentage - path1StatePercentage-path3StatePercentage )))];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.